# How to manually download and install libcrypto.so.1.1 and libssl.so.1.1 with pacman being broken

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

The answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/723616/how-to-fix-missing-libcrypto-so-1-1) put me on the right path but I still have no idea how to manually download these two packages to follow the answer's mentioned steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use the [link provided](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/openssl-1.1/) in the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723723/63286) to the question you linked
   to find the package of the Arch Linux site. You can also [search](https://archlinux.org/packages/)
   for any package in the official repositories. You can also search for something like `libcrypto` and it should list the packages that provide those libraries. In this case the openssl package provides both of the libraries you're looking for.
2. On the package page you can see the Provides line lists the libraries you are looking for. Under the Package Contents section you can expand to show all the files that are in the package to confirm it has the files you are looking for, like `usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1`
3. In the upper right, under Package Actions, click Download From Mirror at the bottom. You should end up with a file like `openssl-1.1-1.1.1.s-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst`.
4. [Extract the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45355277/3511560) with `tar --use-compress-program=unzstd -xvf openssl-1.1-1.1.1.s-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst`
5. In the unpackaged folder, find the files you need at the locations from the file list in step 2 and copy them to the corresponding location on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Instead try copying `/usr/lib/libalmp*` from an USB disk image into your internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix `pacman` temporarily using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Remember to use

```
ldd /usr/bin/pacman
```

to check if libraries are missing. Instead of moving the library needed after download from someplace like browsing to http://mirror.rit.edu/archlinux/core/os/x86_64/ and trying to manually install the missing library, unpack the TAR files in a new local directory and use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/pacmanpanic/usr/lib/
```

where you replace `/root/pacmanpanic/` to wherever you untared the files.

Use `ldd` to check no libraries are missing and that you correctly set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Remember that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` overrides normal library paths to fix issues and can be used to store libraries somewhere else.

Then you can run `pacman` from command line without issue to fix the problem avoiding the use of override. This would be installation of missing packages.